# siunitx - scriptsize engineering notation for exponents

Tags: siunitx

I'm trying to get siunitx to format numbers in a table using 'engineering notation' for exponents, **but with the exponent sign (`E`) in script-size**. I can't seem to figure this out.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage[
    round-mode=places,
    round-precision=1,
    output-exponent-marker=\text{E},
    tight-spacing=true
]{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\noindent The entries in the table should be aligned on the periods and look like this; 12.3{\scriptsize E}3.

\begin{table}[h]

    \caption{Engineering notation with siunitx?}

    \begin{tabular}{S|S}
        12.3E3 & 45.6E3 \\
        7.89E3 & 101.1E3 \\
    \end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Rendered output from example]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301).  Thanks so much for providing a a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) in your very first question.

Comment: Hi @PeterGrill - thanks for the answer and no worries!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `output-exponent-marker={{\scriptstyle E}}` (note the double braces as per @quark67's suggestion) seems to work:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}

\usepackage[
    round-mode=places,
    round-precision=1,
    output-exponent-marker={{\scriptstyle E}},
    tight-spacing=true
]{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\noindent The entries in the table should be aligned on the periods and look like this; 12.3{\scriptsize E}3.

\begin{table}[h]

    \caption{Engineering notation with siunitx?}

    \begin{tabular}{S|S}
        12.3E3 & 45.6e3 \\
        7.89E3 & 101.1E3 \\
    \end{tabular}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As I understood the question correctly, OP like to have only letter E in `\script` size. Close to this is `S[output-exponent-marker=\textsc{e}]` (interestingly, this option doesn't work in `\sisetup`).

Comment: @Zarko With `output-exponent-marker={{\scriptstyle E}}` you will have a small E and a normal full size digit after it.

Comment: @quark67, indeed! I didn't test with two curly braces ...

Comment: @Zarko: Oppss. Thanks for pointing out that subtlty.

Comment: @PeterGrill Why not citing my correction in your answer?

Comment: @quark67: Sorry about that. Corrected now.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you :)